# Correct use of exceptions in javascript

Tags: javascript, exception

Please elaborate on the what exactly this means:

> 'As a general rule, don’t blanket-catch exceptions unless it is for the purpose of “routing” them somewhere—for example, over the network to tell another system that our program crashed. And even then, think carefully about how you might be hiding information.' - Eloquent Javascript

Comment: Basically if you go to the doctor and he discovers you have a problem, he doesn't always simply say "Something is wrong with you" when he could tell you what it is specifically. a.e. "Your arm is broken", "You have Cancer", "You have no sense of humor" - Likewise don't dismiss all errors with "Something went wrong" when you could specifically say "This parameter was incorrect"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the explanation [here](https://eloquentjavascript.net/08_error.html):

> ```
> for (;;) {
>   try {
>     var dir = promtDirection("Where?"); // ← typo!
>     console.log("You chose ", dir);
>     break;
>   } catch (e) {
>     console.log("Not a valid direction. Try again.");
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> The `for (;;)` construct is a way to intentionally create a loop that
>   doesn’t terminate on its own. We break out of the loop only when a
>   valid direction is given. But we misspelled `promptDirection`, which
>   will result in an `“undefined variable”` error. Because the `catch` block
>   completely ignores its exception value (`e`), assuming it knows what the
>   problem is, it wrongly treats the variable error as indicating bad
>   input. Not only does this cause an infinite loop, but it also “buries”
>   the useful error message about the misspelled variable.
>
> As a general rule, don’t blanket-catch exceptions unless it is for the
>   purpose of “routing” them somewhere—for example, over the network to
>   tell another system that our program crashed. And even then, think
>   carefully about how you might be hiding information.
>
> So we want to catch a *specific* kind of exception. We can do this by
>   checking in the catch block whether the exception we got is the one we
>   are interested in and by rethrowing it otherwise. (...)

I believe what the author means by "blanket-catch" exceptions is to catch an exception and don't verify its content at all, believing you are 100% sure it will always be a certain kind of error.

The example code shows a "blanket-catch" that assumed it would only happen when the user provided an *invalid direction*, but the error is actually caused by a typo in the code.

Since the `catch` didn't really verify if the error was really an *invalid direction* (there's no `if` in the `catch`, nor it prints `e`'s content), it caught (swallowed into the oblivion) a different error* believing it was an *invalid direction* one - ultimately handling the exception for the wrong reason.

<sup>* The error would be `undefined is not a function` instead of `undefined variable` as the author points out.</sup>

Comment: I agree, but that's not my code. I was just quoting https://eloquentjavascript.net/08_error.html :P

Comment: Fair enough but let it be known :)